# There at least 4 divisors of $n-1$ which do not divide $\phi(n)$ if $n$ is a composite of the form $6k+1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I observed that if $n$ is a composite number of the form $6k + 1$ then there are at least three divisors of $n - 1$ which do not divide $\phi(n)$ (Euler's totient function). Is this true in general?

Edit 1: As pointed out by Gerry, the same has been posted in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245370/does-composite-number-of-the-form-6k-1-has-at-least-three-non-totient-diviso)

Edit 2: Changed the title after the proof of the claim.

Comment: If not then you must have $\varphi(n)=\frac{n-1}{2}$ or $\varphi(n)=\frac{n-1}{3}$ or $\varphi(n)=\frac{2(n-1)}{3}$

Comment: Clearly if there is a counterexample then it is square-free

Comment: @Peter - You mean there are no counter examples till $10^9$ right?

Comment: Asked and answered on MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/245370/does-composite-number-of-the-form-6k-1-has-at-least-three-non-totient-diviso

Comment: What I meant is that for the numbers upto $10^9$ of the desired type, there are always $4$ numbers dividing $n-1$, but not $\phi(n)$. In particular, I found no counterexample for the given claim. But it seems the claim can be made stronger by replacing "three" by "four".

Comment: Apparantly , the claim has been proven. The next step would be to prove/disprove my stronger claim.

Comment: @Peter: Your claim is true because while making my claim, I was only considering divisors $< n/2$ becuase. So it is trivial to see that if the claim is true for 3 divisors, for divisors $< n/2$ then it will also be true for 4 divisors for divisors $\le n-1$ because $n-1$ is always a non-totient divisors.