# If $n = 18k+5$ is composite, there are at least 9 divisors of $\phi(n)$ which do not divide $n-1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, recreational-mathematics

If $n$ is a composite of the form $18k+5$, there at least 9 divisors of $\phi(n)$ which do not divide $n-1$. Is this true in general or if not, what is the smallest counter example?

**Update**: No counter example for $n \le 1 \times 10^7$.

[Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1874236/there-at-least-4-divisors-of-n-1-which-do-not-divide-phin-if-n-is-a-com).

**Note**: [Posted in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368900/if-n-18k5-is-composite-there-are-at-least-9-divisors-of-phin-which-do) since it did not get an answer in MSE

Comment: The statement is true for $k\le 10^7$

Comment: I meant, your title claim *without* "which do not divide $n-1$, i.e., if $n=18k+5$ is composite, there are at least nine divisors of $\phi(n)$. Do you have a counterexample to that?

Comment: @DietrichBurde No counter example for $n \le 7 \times 10^5$

Comment: See the analogous claim for $n=6k+5$ in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245370/there-at-least-4-divisors-of-n-1-which-do-not-divide-phin-if-n-is-a-com), in the yellow area. This is only about the divisors of $\phi(n)$.

Comment: I am confused, not sure what you are asking. Can you simply state it as a proper math statement ...

Comment: @Peter I have only reached about a million after half a day of computing. Clearly ur code is faster. Do you mind sharing it??

Comment: pari/gp code : ? for(k=10^7,10^8,n=18*k+5;if(ispseudoprime(n)==0,d=divisors(eulerphi(n));d=sele
ct(m->Mod(n-1,m)<>0,d);if(length(d)<=8,print(k,"  ",length(d)))))